# AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlopen'

Tags: python, web-scraping

I just started learning Python. I am sure i wrote the code right.

```
import urllib
import re


stockname = input('Enter the stock name : ')

url = "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuote.jsp?symbol="+stockname+"&illiquid=0&smeFlag=0&itpFlag=0"
htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
htmltext = htmlfile.read()
regex = '<span id="lastPrice">'+stockname+'</span>'
pattern = re.compile(regex)
price = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
print (price)
```

but i keep on getting this error no matter how much i try.

```
Enter the stock name : tcs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\.....\Desktop\stockq.py", line 8, in <module>
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlopen'
```

I tried `urllib.request as well. I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HiMMi\Desktop\stockq.py", line 8, in <module>
    htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  File "C:\Users\HiMMi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\HiMMi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\HiMMi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\HiMMi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\HiMMi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\HiMMi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: Python version?

Comment: @Abhishek i can `print(12)` in python 2.7.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

That does work for py2, but not for Python 3x. For Python 3x, `urlopen` is present in `urllib.request`:

```
import urllib.request

urllib.request.urlopen(...)
```

Comment: And it would be in urllib2 in Python2...